# how can i run all versions of java apps regardless of version without having to be aware of it

Tags: java, version, compatibility

user point of view:
i've had quite a few issues with java apps not running because of wrong version of java.  is there a platform or package out there that would install a few different versions and analyse the version the app was compiled with and run with the most compatible version?

Comment: by having enough machines (physical or virtual) to run all different versions of Java on. but, normally, an older version compiled will run on a newer version of Java, it's the vice versa that tends to causes issues.